# What is the status of `bluez`, and where is the man page?

Tags: bluetooth

`bluez` is [advertised as "Official Linux Bluetooth protocol stack"](http://www.bluez.org/). There's a package (several actually) that can be installed:

```
$ apt-cache search bluez
bluez - Bluetooth tools and daemons
bluez-cups - Bluetooth printer driver for CUPS
bluez-dbg - Bluetooth tools and daemons (with debugging symbols)
bluez-hcidump - Analyses Bluetooth HCI packets
bluez-obexd - bluez obex daemon
bluez-test-scripts - test scripts of bluez
bluez-test-tools - test tools of bluez
bluez-tools - Set of tools to manage Bluetooth devices for linux
```

What is the status of this package? I ask because after installing the `bluez` package, I don't find a `man` page available (there doesn't seem to be a file named `bluez` on my machine). Does anyone else have one? Does it exist? Where can one get a copy? What is used for documentation?

Comment: Last [bluez](http://www.bluez.org/) release was v5.50 in June 2018. From the DEB [file list](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/armhf/bluez/filelist) for 5.43-2 shipped with stretch there should be some man pages for the individual tools and for the daemon.

Comment: `$ man btmgmt` ==> `No manual entry for btmgmt`. Not sure how to navigate the file list, but nothing I saw suggested existence of a man page. Also, nothing listed under [**docs** for bluez](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/armhf/doc/)

Comment: Man pages should be installed at `/usr/share/man` with subdirectories for the sections. Try `man 1 bluetoothctl` or `man 8 bluetoothd` for example. Online, try here: https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/bluez/index.html

Comment: Apparently `bluetoothd` = `bluez`... who knew? The [file list](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/armhf/bluez/filelist) you linked to is a big help in getting a handle on this. Maybe it's just me, but the "bluez universe" seems to be characterized by substandard documentation.

Comment: According to the package contents there should be 19 man pages installed but looking at them they're pretty sparse. How about https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/README and https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc ?

Comment: `zcat /usr/share/doc/bluez/README.Debian.gz` was somewhat helpful, but again falls well short of the mark. The github site has a lot more. I got curious about this when I learned of the `btmgmt` utiity, but was unable to figure how it worked (no man pg). This all counts as progress, if not an answer. Would you like to take a stab at assembling all you've presented here as an answer?

Comment: Just to underscore the 'substandard documentation' point, enter `btmgmt info` at the command line & study the output for a moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the time of writing the latest [BlueZ](http://www.bluez.org/) release was v5.50 back in June 2018 whilst v5.43-2 is available in the Stretch repositories. Installing the `bluez` package should have installed 19 or so `man` pages along with the usual Debian `README.Debian.gz` file, you can see the list of files installed by the package on it's page on the [Debian Packages](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/armhf/bluez/filelist) site.

You can also view the `man` pages online at the [Debian Manpages](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/bluez/index.html) site. Unfortunately the `btmgmt` tool you're interested in does not have a `man` page but it does offer some built-in help with `btmgmt <command> --help`.

As you've noted, the documentation in the supplied `man` pages is quite sparse and (to me, anyway) feels like there's a missing "overview" document somewhere that should be read first. You may have more luck going straight to the "source" and looking through some of the files in the code repository at https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree, the "doc" directory contains several text files but from a cursory look they seem to be more about the kernel API than using the userland tools as an end-user.

Comment: Good answer +1. If you don't mind, I'll wait a day or two to select an answer; that may encourage other "BlueZ cogniscenti" to come forward & shed more light on this.

Comment: Not a problem, it's sad that so many "cornerstone" GNU/Linux projects and technologies have such bad documentation (even a basic wiki would help). If you do make some headway and you feel that way inclined you could contribute to the documentation to improve it: it's open source after all. Good luck.

Comment: That's a fair comment: "don't bitch, contribute". And in general I agree with that. However, after submitting a few legitimate bug reports (see `man reportbug` :) to the debian team, I've concluded that they are just not interested in bug reports from the rank and file user community. And so, I've chosen not to waste my time in that fashion.

Answer (score 3):

### UPDATE 1: Sep 25, 2020:

- The `bluetoothd` (aka **Bluez**) version remains at 5.5 in RPi OS `buster`
- The date stamp at the bottom of `man bluetoothd` still has a 2004 date stamp
- The [list of *Bluetooth-related* man pages for `buster` is here](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/bluez/index.html)
- The quality of the Bluetooth documentation for RPi still sucks.

That is all.

### UPDATE 2: Nov 2, 2020:

Still no improvements on the documentation AFAIK, but I did make some (painful & slow) progress on getting Bluetooth to do something useful on my system - [streaming music to a BT speaker](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/116819/bluetooth-blues-redux/116843#116843).

---

#### Please feel free to edit this answer, or comment if you have better information on the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

***Question***

> What is the status of BlueZ, and where is the man page?

***Answer***

Yes, I could not find good documentation on BlueZ V5.50 installation.

*[My disappointing progress report on installing BlueZ V5.50.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99017/connection-failed-between-raspberry-pi-zero-w-and-android-via-bluetooth-le)*

> I have just found a very detailed guide on how to install BlueZ V5.50
>   on Rpi's including ***Rpi4B***.  I hope to try it soon and then report
>   my progress.

***References***

(1) [Developer Study Guide: Deploying BlueZ v5.50 on Raspberry Pi Board (Including Rpi4B)](https://3pl46c46ctx02p7rzdsvsg21-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/1908_Tutorial-How-to-set-up-BlueZ__UpdateLFC_FINAL.pdf)

(2) [Bluetooth Mesh Models Technical Overview](https://3pl46c46ctx02p7rzdsvsg21-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/1903_Mesh-Models-Overview_FINAL.pdf)