# Bluetooth discoverable mode is automatically turned OFF

Tags: raspbian, boot, bluetooth

I want to set up the Bluetooth on boot so I can connect to it whenever I want with a device which is not trusted by the Raspberry Pi Bluetooth. I set up the Bluetooth on boot on my Raspberry Pi this way. In /etc/rc.local, I added :

```
sudo bluetoothctl <<EOF
power on
discoverable on
pairable on
EOF

sudo hciconfig hci0 sspmode 0
sudo bt-agent -c NoInputNoOutput -p /root/bluetooth.cfg &
```

I use a Bluetooth configuration file to secure the Bluetooth connection, more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34709583/bluetoothctl-set-passkey/52164888#52164888)

The problem is, after some time (~3 minutes), the discoverable mode is automatically turned OFF and I cannot connect to

Another problem is, after a device connect/disconnect, the discoverable mode is also turned OFF.

Is this possible to keep the discoverable mode ON every time and even if some Bluetooth devices connect/disconnect to the Raspberry ?

Edit: I'm using the Raspberry Pi Model B V1.2

Comment: Yes, I have spent over 10 hours doing what you are doing and finding what you are finding.  I read that Rpi3 BLE (BlueLink or similar) is not well supported.  Now I have just installed buster, waiting for Rpi4 (ordered a couple of days ago from a shop in stock) & will try again.  BTW, I am using Rpi stretch 9 GUI desktop and installed all BLE stuff I searched.  But then I read that BLE config files scattered here and there and some of them crash with each other. ( https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99017/connection-failed-between-raspberry-pi-zero-w-and-android-via-bluetooth-le )

Comment: You think it's because of the RPI Bluetooth chip ? It seems to work fine but, I think that, after 3 minutes, the discoverable mode is automatically shutdown to save power.
I will soon try with the Raspberry Pi Compute Module 3 and the ATWILC3000 chip. I'll keep you informed if this resolve the problem.

Comment: No, I am not saying the hardware, ie, BLE chip is problematic.  It is the BLE software drivers that are buggy, or not up to date.  Rpi 4 has BT5, so I hope they have a less buggy version.  A couple of years ago, I also played with Blue Tooth serial modules, and I also found the BT connections not reliable, with frequent disconnections and need to annoyingly hardware reset. I did try over 10 modules (HC/HM 04/05/10 etc) then.  This time I also order "improved" version of BLE 4.0 but not yest tried.  Hope you have luck with CM3 and the other BT chip (built into CM3, not an USB module?) .

Comment: I hope so... I only have to send/receive a small amount of data. Indeed, I want to use the Bluetooth connection so the user can enable the hostapd.service without access to the Raspberry Pi. The solution may be to write a small script ?
The CM3 has no built-in Wi-Fi/BT, so the ATWILC3000 is an external serial module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I continued my research and found an [answer](https://github.com/ole-vi/bluetooth-server#step-5---set-the-discoverabletimeout-to-0-in-the-file-etcbluetoothmainconf) that works for me. There is a `DiscoverableTimeout` on `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` which is, by default, set to 300s.

I just add `DiscoverableTimeout = 0` on this configuration files.

Comment: How nice.  So you have solved the Blue Tooth problem that have been disturbing so many newbies for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to *trust* the device you are trying to connect to through Bluetooth of the Raspberry Pi (look up help menu for list of available commands).  I could only get partial pairing enabled on my iPhone, until I trusted the iPhone MAC address.