# Wifi Speakers like bluetooth speakers using raspberry pi 3b+

Tags: raspbian, wifi, audio, bluetooth, speakers

So basically I was able to use my raspberry pi as a bluetooth audio out device that is, connecting a speaker via audio jack I'm able to make it a Bluetooth speaker. I'm wondering if there's a specific protocol/package/anything that allows the same using wifi, as my bluetooth connection feels pretty slow always. I intend to use my phone's wifi hotspot and use the pi as a reciever that reroutes the audio to the 3.5mm out just like bluetooth. I'm running a raspian stretch on my raspberry pi 3B+. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am a bit confused. I usually use Rpi desktop VLC Media Player to play mp3 files and output to a Bluetooth speaker. I have never heard of Wifi speaker. I think there is no such thing. I also use my smart phone to listen to radio using Bluetooth head phone or Bluetooh speaker： https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99017/connection-failed-between-raspberry-pi-zero-w-and-android-via-bluetooth-le. I guess you are connecting your smart phone to Rpi and output to Rpi's 3.5mm jack. This connection seems a bit indirect.

Comment: I don't know if my question is getting misinterpreted here lol but actually I don't have a Bluetooth speaker or a WiFi speaker... I use my raspberry and it's audio out along with an old speaker amplifier kit... So it's already a portable music box with an added powerbank inside the box. What I'm trying to achieve here is rather than using Bluetooth to play music from my phone on the pi-speaker, is there any way to play music or stream music from phone via WiFi

Comment: Sorry about the weird way of asking.I have made some edits to the question to make it easier to understand

Comment: Yes, I think I misunderstood your question.  Let me tried again.  (1) For now you don't have any Bluetooth speaker nor "Wifi speaker" (which I doubt it exists).  (2) For now you have a "portable music box" which consists of the following: (a) Rpi, (b) Power amplifier and speaker connected to Rpi's 3.5mm jack. (c) power bank. (c) Monitor, keyboard, and mouse connected to Rpi (direct or SSH).  (3) Now what  you wish to do now to connect you smart phone to Rpi, using Wifi or Bluetooth, and use your phone to play music or listen to radio.  Please confirm if I am guessing correctly this time. :)

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want... To use my phone to stream music not using raspicast or anything but directly... I wish to play offline music as well as stream music from Spotify and SoundCloud.

Comment: Ah, your question seems to be a general (and straightforward) one about smart phone connecting to Rp using Wifi or Bluetooth.  But I am not too sure, because I know too little about Spotify or SoundCloud.  I think I better pass your question to other guys who have a better and bigger picture of what is going on.  In the mean time perhaps I can learn more about Spotify and SounCloud and catch you guys soon. :)

Comment: I have individual solutions for Spotify -raspotify but it requires Spotify premium. For offline music I can use raspicast and play almost all music and even YouTube ig. Similiar solutions exist for SoundCloud also but I just want to know if there's an all in all solution

Answer (score 1):

Install `shairport-sync` and it will advertise an RAOP (AirPlay 1) service on your WiFi. Apple gear will all detect this and offer it as an audio destination, Linux, Windows and others can too.

Comment: Why do you suggest to install `shairport-sync`? There was nothing asked about audio streams from iTunes, iOS devices and third-party AirPlay  sources.

Comment: @Ingo OP asks for "any way to play music or stream music from phone via WiFi" — that's AirPlay. If there's an implementation of ChromeCast Audio for the Pi that would seem to be the main alternative.