# Two Bluetooth headphones connected to the RPi 4 B at the same time?

Tags: bluetooth

Has anybody successfully connected two Bluetooth headphones to the RPi 4 at the same time?
What profiles does it support?

Comment: Hi @Bostjan, I spent 10 hours trying to pair/connect Bluetooth speakers/headohones to Rpi3B stretch, ended up total failure.  Then tried again another 5 hours on Rpi4B buster (July 10 release) and only managed to successfully to pair/connect one of four Bouetooth devices, which pair/connect without any problem with my SamSung Galaxy C9 Pro.  Win10 with an external dongle not so smooth though.  My conclusion is: Rpi4B Bluetooth with BlueZ still have a problem: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99017/connection-failed-between-raspberry-pi-zero-w-and-android-via-bluetooth-ble-blue

Comment: I have managed to connect only one Bluetooth headphone at a time.

Comment: Yes I read that BlueTooth is a one-to-one protocol, like RS232 UART serial.  Usually it is only the bus type, like  I2C, SPI, that can connect many devices on the same bus.  An analogy is the home mains 200VAC power bus, that can entertain many guys on the same bus, but of course that is power, not data signals.  In other words, bad luck, one only, my friend.