# Bluetooth and wifi settings not working correctly

Tags: wifi, bluetooth, headless

I'm working on a project regarding a headless Raspberry Pi 3 B+
The Raspberry have to work as a Bluetooth-speaker with a HifiBerry Amp2 hat on top. The Bluetooth has to be open, and able to accept the connection. Therefore  the ability to auto connect and auto trust any device is mandatory.
The raspberry pi should also work as a WiFi AP without password. A open WiFi without internet connection, but with the possibility to access Node-Red dashboard on `xx.xx.xx.xx:1880/ui`

I've tried with installing Super-Simple-Raspberry-Pi-Audio-Receiver-Install but never got it working. I got several "fatal errors". I've got the raspberry to work as a AP - but never open.

Has anyone succeeded with the Bluetooth auto-connect?

Thanks!

Benjamin

Comment: I once spent 10 hours or so and finally succeeded to connect a Bluetooth speaker to Rpi4: 
Connection failed between raspberry pi zero w and android via bluetooth LE
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99017/connection-failed-between-raspberry-pi-zero-w-and-android-via-bluetooth-le