# What is this prompt saying about bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, bluez, dbus

I tried to fix some problems with the bluetooth and uninstall pi-bluetooth. Also installed it .But the problems are bigger now. What is this prompt saying.
[image: promp]

Comment: BlueZ5.5 is not working smoothly on Rpi3B+ and Rpi4B. You might like to try the newest guide from offoical BlueZ: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96207/what-is-the-status-of-bluez-and-where-is-the-man-page